# remove sidebar shop page woocommerce

Tags: php, javascript, woocommerce

I've been desperately searching for help with this. I would really love to remove the sidebar only from my woocommerce shop base page. In the admin options for my theme there's a place to enable the sidebar on the product page but what you select there impacts not just the shop base page but all of the archive pages.

Within the archive-product.php file there's code that controls the layout based on if that button is enabled so I thought my best bet would be to use an if else statement to say if its the shop page, use the 'no-sidebar' class. This is what I came up with but it's not working. Any thoughts would be fantastic.

```
<?php if ( is_object( $shop_page) ) : ?>
<div id="default_products_page_container" class="no-sidebar">
<?php elseif (have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id"default_products_page_container" class="with-sidebar">
```

Answer (score 6):

In functions.php of your child theme:

```
// remove sidebar for woocommerce pages 
add_action( 'get_header', 'remove_storefront_sidebar' );
function remove_storefront_sidebar() {
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
```

and in css you'll have to change content class to be 100% width, for my theme:

```
 .post-type-archive-product .content-area {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove sidebar from the shop page you want to use action hook in   **function.php** file -

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'remove_sidebar' );
    function remove_sidebar()
    {
        if ( is_shop() ) { 
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
       }
    }
```

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove the sidebar and make the page full width. This working example is the correct way to do it.

1 - The ID `#secondary` is the sidebar ID. Make the page full with we apply style to `#primary width:100%;`

2 - The line `if(is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_product())` removes the sidebar from cart, checkout, and product pages respectively.

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_sidebar' ); 
function hide_sidebar(){ 
  if(is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_product()){ 
  ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    #secondary {
        display: none;
    }
    #primary {
       width:100%;
    }
   </style>
  <?php
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out the theme you are using and remove the code for the sidebar from the template.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to remove the sidebar from the shop base page ONLY.  Since the only template for the shop page also controls the category pages if I remove the code from the template it affects the other "archive" pages.

Comment: Just set a variable on the base page and check if it is that page when including sidebar code

Answer (score 0):

I’m using

- WooCommerce 5.6.0
- shopstore theme version 4.2.9

I solved modifying the woocommerce wrapper functions in the script **inc/woocommerce.php**

Here the changes:

In

```
function shopstore_woocommerce_wrapper_before()
```

I replaced

```
$arg = array( 'column' => 'col-md-8' );
```

with

```
$sidebar_column = 'col-md-4 no-sidebar-actived';
$column = 'col-md-12';
$sidebar = 'inactive';
$arg = array( 'section' => 'page-container', 'column' => $column, 'sidebar'=>$sidebar , 'sidebar_column' => $sidebar_column );
```

While in

```
function shopstore_woocommerce_wrapper_after()
```

I replaced

```
$arg = array( 'sidebar' => 'active' );
```

with

```
$arg = array( 'sidebar' => 'inactive' );
```

So, in I used the same strategy of the no-sidebar template (in the script **custom-template/no-sidebar.php**) in the creation of the shop page.